# Jquery - Span Containing effekcts all span on page

Tags: jquery

I have this code its working way to good, in that sense that in make display:none on all spans on page and not only this field.

Can anyone see whats wrong and why it applies to all spands and not only $TField.?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('label[for=customfield" . $TField->id . "], input#customfield" . $TField->id .   "').hide();
$('#frmCheckout').find('span:contains(\"" . $TField->description . "\")').hide();
$('.form-group').find('span:contains(\"" . $TField->description . "\")').hide();
});
```

I have looked at a number of post here but cant figure this quite out why its effectic all spans on page and not just this one.

Comment: This isn't just JS/jQuery.  It looks like PHP generating JS.  Take a look at the code that ends up generated in the page. (Absent a more comprehensive example, we can't see what that generated code actually looks like.)